# Doctrine: how to create a query using "LIKE REPLACE"?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

this SQL clause is working OK:

```
SELECT * FROM `sf_guard_user` WHERE nombre_apellidos LIKE REPLACE('Mar Sanz',' ','%')
```

Now I'm trying to write this query for Doctrine. I have tried this:

```
$query->andWhere(sprintf('%s.%s LIKE REPLACE (?," ","%")',
                         $query->getRootAlias(), $fieldName),
                 'Mar Sanz'));
```

but I get this error:

```
Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A '%' must be doubled ('%%') to mean a literal % inside of a pattern string you sent to `sprintf` or `printf`:

```
$query->andWhere(sprintf('%s.%s LIKE REPLACE (?," ","%%")',
                         $query->getRootAlias(), $fieldName),
                 'Mar Sanz'));
```

**Suggestion:** Why not run the string-replacement function inside the code before you send it to the database server?

```
$query->andWhere(
    sprintf(
        '%s.%s LIKE ?',
        $query->getRootAlias(),
        $fieldName
    ),
    preg_replace('/ /', '%', 'Mar Sanz')
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Does your suggestion have any advantage?